# Colocando na ordem os valores no dicionario

Tags: python

```
array_mais_tocadas = {}
contador_de_play = {'Rad':156,'Kiki':141,'The black':35,'Neutral':94}
mais_tocada = 0
menos_tocada = 0

for x, y in  contador_de_play.items():
    if(y > mais_tocada):
        mais_tocada = y
        array_mais_tocadas[x] = mais_tocada
    if(y < menos_tocada or menos_tocada == 0):
        menos_tocada = y
        array_mais_tocadas[x] = menos_tocada
```

Ele não esta funcionando da maneira correta e colocando na ordem do maior para o menor, onde eu errei??

**OBS: Eu não posso usar min ou max**

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente porque você não está fazendo uma ordenação, você apenas está atualizando os valores em determinadas posições seguindo a regra se ela foi mais tocada ou menos tocada em relação às anteriores.

Outro ponto é que essencialmente o dicionário no Python é uma representação do conceito da tabela hash, criando uma relação um para um entre chaves e valores e, portanto, não faz sentido pensar em "ordenar" um dicionário.

Você até pode utilizar a estrutura `collections.OrderedDict` que é uma extensão ao dicionário em que é mantida a ordem de inserção, então para isso você precisará desconstruir o seu dicionário em uma estrutura que faça sentido ser ordenada para então criar um `OrderedDict`. Com a função `sorted` você consegue retornar as chaves do seu dicionário de forma ordenada conforme o valor associado e, assim, criar o `OrderedDict` na sequência que deseja:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


original = {'Rad':156,'Kiki':141,'The black':35,'Neutral':94}
result = OrderedDict((key, original[key]) for key in sorted(original, key=original.get, reverse=True))

for key, value in result.items():
  print(f'{key}: {value}')

# Rad: 156
# Kiki: 141
# Neutral: 94
# The black: 35
```

Comment: A partir da versão 3.7 os dicionários mantém a ordem de inserção das chaves. O dicionário pode ser ordenado com `sorted(dicionario)` por exemplo.

Comment: @PauloMarques Bem lembrado quanto à ordem na versão 3.7+, mas não entendi a segunda parte. Como assim ordenar usando apenas `sorted(dicionario)`?

Comment: apenas um exemplo de ordenação pelas chaves. Adicionei uma resposta

Answer (score 0):

A partir da versão 3.7 os dicionários mantém a ordem de inserção das chaves.

```
contador_de_play = {'Rad':156,'Kiki':141,'The black':35,'Neutral':94}

sorted_contador_de_play = dict(sorted(contador_de_play.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

print(sorted_contador_de_play)
```

Resultado

```
{'Rad': 156, 'Kiki': 141, 'Neutral': 94, 'The black': 35}
```